# Stress concentrations around rivets in compression

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, structural-analysis, buckling, rivets

The stress concetration factor for an unfilled hole is around 3, but it decreases when a rivet is present. What factor can we expect for a hole with a rivet in it in compression?

Comment: It is highly dependent on the fitness state of the installation. What is the significance of this question?

Comment: It's a compression panel for a rocket launcher (simplified to a non-curved sheet of metal) with stringers attached by rivets. To calculate the compressive force at which inter-rivet buckling occurs, I need to get the maximum stress around the hole with the rivet in it.

Comment: The occurrence of buckling requires both stress and freedom of deflection or displacement of the material. At the rivet joint, the stress is high, but usually, the displacement is restricted. I suggest posting a diagram to better depict the question.

Answer (score 0):

In general, stress concentration factors are defined for loading that have tensile forces (due to tension, bending or torsion).

IMHO, this is due to the fact that stress concentrations are a way of dealing with crack development in structures. Tensile stresses open up crack lines and at each development of the crack energy is released (see Griffith's Energy Release Rate). When compressive forces are applied any crack presented close up and there is rarely any propagation, so there is no reason for concentration factors.